# SpeechSynthesis Pause button needed

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Hi im trying to create a pause button for this.   Here's what i have

```
function onClickPlay() {
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Once upon a time it was the middle of winter the flakes of snow were falling like feathers from the sky";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

i need a onClickPause()

I havn't tried anything because im not to good with javascript